# PHP Zend Framework: How do I make ZF Tool work with extended Controller_Actions?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller, zend-tool

I'm working with a Zend Framework project and using the ZF tool from the command line.  After setting up some initial structure, I extended the Zend_Controller_Action class with something like MySite_Controller_Action and made the existing controllers point to that.  So now I have something like:

```
class IndexController extends MySite_Controller_Action
{  ... }
```

and

```
abstract class MySite_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action
{ ... }
```

The problem is that now when I attempt to run a command like

```
Bash$ zf create action edit Index
```

I get an error like this:

```
Creating an action named edit inside controller at /Library/WebServer/Documents/MySite/application/controllers/IndexController.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MySite_Controller_Action' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/MySite/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 3

Fatal error: Class 'MySite_Controller_Action' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/OurMods/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 3
```

Can anyone offer up any ideas?  I've done a little searching, but I don't even know where to start on this one.

**NOTE:** I HAVE loaded a 'MySite' namespace via the application.ini file as follows:

```
autoloadernamespaces.MySite = "MySite_"
```

Comment: I too have hit this roadblock. Looks like I have to go with plugins and helpers as explained here http://devzone.zend.com/1218/action-helpers-in-zend-framework/